# Session is created even if "SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS" is set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

HttpSession is created despite "SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS".
Detailed Implementation:https://github.com/r-fujiyama/spring-app/blob/master/src/main/java/app/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  private final ErrorAuthenticationEntryPoint errorAuthenticationEntryPoint;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain v2APISsecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
      APIKeyAuthenticationProvider apiKeyAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher("/v2/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v2/user/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement((session) -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        )
        .apply(new APIKeyAuthenticationFilterConfig()).and()
        .authenticationProvider(apiKeyAuthenticationProvider)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(errorAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    return http.build();
  }

}
```

```
2023-08-23T01:06:09.169+09:00 INFO  14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] app.filter.LoggingFilter                 : START, GET /api/v2/user/1?userType=Private&firstName=taro&lastName=nihon&age=20, client=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, headers=[host:"localhost:8080", connection:"keep-alive", ___internal-request-id:"993d73e7-8f3d-404b-aec2-02d674a31145", sec-ch-ua:""Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"", api-key:"*****", sec-ch-ua-mobile:"?0", user-agent:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", sec-ch-ua-platform:""Windows"", accept:"*/*", sec-fetch-site:"none", sec-fetch-mode:"cors", sec-fetch-dest:"empty", accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, br", accept-language:"ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"], body=
2023-08-23T01:06:09.169+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/v1/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@321ca237, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4c5a2baf, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@45900b64, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@58a2d9f9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@1ec22831, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@580fd26b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4087c7fc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@79f90a3a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@91f565d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@63f855b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@22ad1bae, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@32456db0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@c689973]] (1/2)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.170+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/v2/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1e84f3c8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5f59ea8c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@57a6a933, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6f3f0ae, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@7b2ccba5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@69aa7d76, app.security.APIKeyAuthenticationFilter@64f9f455, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5b5b59, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1934ad7c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5d5a51b1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6baf25d7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@363c32cc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@f1266c6]] (2/2)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.170+09:00 DEBUG 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /v2/user/1?userType=Private&firstName=taro&lastName=nihon&age=20
2023-08-23T01:06:09.170+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.170+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.170+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking APIKeyAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with APIKeyAuthenticationProvider (1/2)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 DEBUG 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created HttpSession as SecurityContext is non-default
2023-08-23T01:06:09.171+09:00 DEBUG 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken [Principal=, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1dd1a1cc]
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (11/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken [Principal=, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
2023-08-23T01:06:09.172+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@9d2e8c]
2023-08-23T01:06:09.173+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@9d2e8c] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$742/0x0000000801049308@751529a
2023-08-23T01:06:09.173+09:00 DEBUG 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /v2/user/1?userType=Private&firstName=taro&lastName=nihon&age=20
2023-08-23T01:06:09.185+09:00 TRACE 14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-08-23T01:06:09.185+09:00 INFO  14632 [Trace-ID:1a177cbc-ca12-49f3-9085-1c018c6596e5] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] app.filter.LoggingFilter                 : END, headers=[Vary:Origin, Vary:Origin, Vary:Origin, Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=D4588822282DB3BE32328A76869F809D; Path=/api; HttpOnly, X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff, X-XSS-Protection:0, Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, Pragma:no-cache, Expires:0, X-Frame-Options:DENY], body={"user":{"id":1,"type":"Private","status":"Registered","firstName":"taro","lastName":"nihon","age":20},"status":"Success","errors":[]}
```

I would like to know the configuration or implementation to prevent HttpSession from being generated.

Comment: The STATELESS will ensure no session is created by Spring security, however that does not mean that your application will not create any session. This policy only applies to Spring security context. You might still see JSESIONID in your application, so don't think that spring security configurations are not working.

Comment: The log shows 'Stored SecurityContextImpl...' and it looks like the session was created by Spring Security, is that wrong?

Comment: Just read all the logs and you will see `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1dd1a1cc` it is from web, controller layer, it is from tomcat that implements `HttpSession`

Comment: update: StandardSessionFacade is an tomcat class that implements HttpSession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by implementing a filter that extends `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`.
By default, this implementation uses `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`, so an HttpSession is created.
The solution is to set `NullSecurityContextRepository` or `RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository` to `SecurityContextRepository`.

```java
public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

  public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    // HttpSession will not be created if either 
    // of the following SecurityContextRepository is set.
    setSecurityContextRepository(new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository());
    // or
    setSecurityContextRepository(new NullSecurityContextRepository());
  }

...
}
```